# Parsing data from vue component with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have a vue component called "testrow". Within it, I have a form with 2 selections, 1st is "description", 2nd is "parameter". My script should run in a way where the "parameter" changes according to the corresponding 'description' in my database. This is done with a function in my controller called by my web route. I am using ajax in my function in methods called "populate" as follows:

```
methods: {
        populate: ()=>{
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url:'/parametersByDescription',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {description: description},
                success: function(data){ 
                    store.parameter = data;
                }
            })              
            return;
        }
    }
```

I am having trouble sending the "description" value as a key named "description" to my function as it is undefined in the portion of the code below:

```
data: {description: description},
```

I cannot find the proper name for the "description" value I wish to use. Typically, {description: vm.description} would be used, however, since this is a vue component and all data, methods and :name from templates are isolated within the component called "testrow", and I do not know what its "name" is.

In the Vue Devtools, I have Root and Testrow, and within Testrow/data, I have "description" where the "description" value I want resides.

Comment: Have you tried using : data: {description: this.description}

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I just did so by using data: {description: this.something} where something is pre-defined. I have changed my function in my controller to reflect the value of "something". This is the error message I got from Vue Devtools:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined
    at VueComponent.populate (create:743)
    at invoker (app.js:38145)
    at HTMLSelectElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (app.js:37944)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should use `this` when scope is not changed, so within arrow function, it would be used like this: `this.description`.

However, when you use jQuery or some other external library, scope is changed, and `this` refers to other object then.

Solution is to assign Vue object to some new variable, that would be used then within changed scope. Also, make sure you have declared and defined your `description` either as a prop, or as a model:

```
data(){
    return{
        description : '', //declare and define
    }
},
methods: {
    populate: ()=>{
        var self = this; //assigning Vue's this to self variable
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url:'/parametersByDescription',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {description: self.description}, //using it instead of this.
            success: function(data){
                self.store.parameter = data; //probably needed here too
            }
        })
        return;
    }
}
```

so in addition of providing description as model in component's template:

```
<input v-model="description"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I now understand that I need a way to refer to the scope I am in. Unfortunately this method did not work, are there other ways to refer to the scope?

Comment: it looks like then that description is not existing, not as a model, not as prop. Maybe you should provide it within template and data as a model?

Comment: Yep! I avoided adding more props but I added description in the data of root and called the value with data{description: vm.description} thanks!

Comment: it works, it's not really what I need in this case, but it's cool.